# Rails 4 + Devise + Paperclip + S3 Example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Can anyone upload a simple, working Rails 4 + Devise + Paperclip + S3 example application (to GitHub or something)? I just want to upload an avatar to S3 with Paperclip in the User model. I really can't get this working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this yourself ? It's really straightforward.

In your gemfile:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk1'
```

Follow instructions at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

After that follow paperclip instructions

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/

Pay attention to your S3 region (s3_host_name, use the eu-west url if in eu etc.):

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_host_name => 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  :bucket => 'S3_BUCKET_NAME'
}
```

And your done!

This way, by reading the install instructions you also won't forget to install things like Imagemagick, the library where paperclip depends on.